# Kernel density estimation bandwidth Rule of thumb: 2.575 factor?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

The paper by Epperlein and Smillie "Cracking VAR with kernels" reports usage of a $2.575\sigma/N^{-1/5}$ bandwidth for kernel *quantile* estimation, differing from the usual Deheuvels/Silverman 1.059 factor used for *density* estimation. Silverman is cited as a source. Are the different settings the reason for such a discrepancy (which I doubt given the common exponent, as opposed to a common -1/3 for quantiles), is it a different kernel or something else? Any other (online) source for such constant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the part you're asking about is this part of the paper:

> It can be shown (See Silverman 1986) that the optimal choice for $h$ (in the sense of minimising the mean square error)
>   for the ***triangular kernel*** is
>
> $h=2.575\sigma N^{-\frac15}$

Note that the paper you mention references Silverman 1986 ... whose book is on *density estimation* (that's even the title). The bandwidth calculation they refer to is for density estimation.

This particular one derives from Silverman's optimal bandwidth estimator (see [here](https://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode15.html) for example). If we start with equation 3.2.1 in Silverman's book (that you mentioned):

$$h_\text{opt}=k_2^{-2/5}\left\{ \int K(t)^2 \text{d}t \right\}^{1/5}\left\{ \int f''(x)^2\text{d}x \right\}^{-1/5} n^{-1/5}$$

where $k_2=\int t^2 K(t) dt$.

and substitute a particular assumption for $f$, then a particular kernel for $K$ will yield an optimal bandwidth. Different kernels have different constants. Using Gaussian for both gives 1.059

The figure 2.575 is for the triangular kernel. I currently don't know for certain what is used for $f$ to get that but my current belief is that it's based on Gaussian $f$. (Edit: yes, it looks like that belief was correct; I took some time to sit and work it through.)

Calculating:

$K(t) = (1-|t|) I_{[-1,1]}$

$k_2=\int t^2 K(t) dt = \frac16$; $\int K(t)^2 \text{d}t = \frac23$; $\int f''(x)^2\text{d}x = \frac{3}{8\sqrt{\pi}}\sigma^{-5}$

$$h_\text{opt}=k_2^{-2/5}\left\{ \int K(t)^2 \text{d}t \right\}^{1/5}\left\{ \int f''(x)^2\text{d}x \right\}^{-1/5} n^{-1/5}$$

$$ = (36\cdot \frac23\cdot \frac{8\sqrt{\pi}}{3})^{\frac15}\sigma n^{-\frac15}$$

$$ = (64\sqrt{\pi})^{\frac15}\sigma n^{-\frac15}$$

$$ = 2.576 \sigma n^{-\frac15}$$

The discrepancy in the last figure is almost certainly due to premature rounding (specifically, it may be due to taking the rounded off value for a value related to $\int f''(x)^2\text{d}x$ in the Gaussian case directly from Silverman).

Comment: Thanks for digging this out! However I do not see mention to the issue of *quantile* vs *density* estimation (and the possibly different exponent), which the question was about...  is all this then just for the latter case? (the link you provided seems broken from here) Maybe should I make it more explicit in the question title?

Comment: @Quartz see my edit for the regression vs density estimation issue. I'll have to remove the link; it used to work (I was using it as I wrote the answer!). It's not important; Silverman's book has the details.